# How to find if less is installed on the system?

Tags: c, system

I would like the following behavior without the use of `system`

```
int ret = system("less -V > /dev/null 2>&1");
if (ret == 0) {
    printf("The less executable was found.\n");
}
```

I need the variable `ret` to be 0 if less is installed on the system, but without using the call to `system`. Can it be done with `exec` or similar?

Comment: *but without using the call to `system`*. That's a strange requirement.

Comment: Yup, very strange. You would need to fork() and probably want to use execlp() and this would only work on Linux not on BSD based Unix  (as documented here (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Comment: It's our requirement to learn C that we don't "cheat" and use the system call because the problem is part of an exercise to learn C89 without using the system call, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `system("which less")` to determine whether `less` is installed. This avoids attempting to invoke `less` if it isn't installed. If you don't want to use `system` at all, you'll have to re-implement the functionality of `which` in your program: i.e., use `getenv` to get the `PATH` variable and try appending `/less` to each path and invoking `stat` on the resulting file to determine if it exists and is executable.

Comment: Can you please elaborate because I never used `stat` before?

Comment: @Niklasinstockholm It's a system call, not part of the C standard but standardized as part of POSIX. It gives you the metadata associated with the file.